# Get the weather for cities with names that contain spaces using Openweathermap

Tags: ios, swift, weather-api, openweathermap

I am trying to get the weather for a city using [Openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org/) using this code:

```
func getWeatherByCity(city: String) {
    if let weatherRequestURL = NSURL(string: "\(openWeatherMapBaseURL)?APPID=\(openWeatherMapAPIKey)&q=\(city)") {
        getWeather(weatherRequestURL: weatherRequestURL)
    }
}
```

(The full tutorial http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/04/02/how-to-build-an-ios-weather-app-in-swift-part-1-a-very-bare-bones-weather-app/)

The api works fine with city names that don't contain spaces.

even on the home page http://openweathermap.org/ , looking for san francisco gives no results.

What's missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @SaintThread suggestion, removing spaces is done by replacing occurrences of the spaces with an empty String:

```
containsPlacemark.locality?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

But after contacting the support team, they recommended using underscores instead of spaces. Here is an excerpt from their email:

> Indeed, spaces support is broken. Please just replace them with
>   underscores. Indeed, you can just omit spaces spelling “San Francisco”
>   as “SanFrancisco” but this manner can cause unexpected results with
>   some particular cities, “San_Francisco” is the best form.

So the correct way to deal with this is the following:

```
containsPlacemark.locality?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to replace spaces in your city name by **+** sign

```
let string = "San Francisco"
let replaced = (string as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
```

[image]
If you look on address bar - it replaces spaces with plus itself.

For this site we need to remove spaces:
[image]

Not sure why they claim that their search engine is very flexible :)

Comment: I used `return containsPlacemark.locality?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")` , it's cleaner

Comment: yes, but you are replacing with empty space when idea is to replace with "+"

Comment: You must remove the space, if you try with the + you have no results.

Comment: when I search for "SanFrancisco" I get "Not found"
when I search for "San Francisco" I get SF from Colombia and Argentina but not from the USA. Any ideas?

Comment: @jreft56 you need to enter "San Francisco, US" it works for me. They changed API during these three years :)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the space, so `San Francisco` becomes `SanFrancisco`. In  http://openweathermap.org/ it works.

You can check this thread:
https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/16280015-my-city-shows-up-as-http-openweathermap-org-city-?t=535697

Answer (score 0):

Today I was facing the same issue and was able to fix it as follow:

```
city = city.split(' ').join('+');
```